# Efficiently combining groupby, last and count in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

From a list of logs, i want to get the number of active events at each timestamp for a specific event type.

A sample log input looks like this:

| time | id | event |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-03-01 10:00 | 1 | A |
| 2022-03-01 11:00 | 2 | B |
| 2022-03-01 12:00 | 3 | A |
| 2022-03-01 13:00 | 1 | B |
| 2022-03-01 14:00 | 4 | A |
| 2022-03-01 15:00 | 2 | C |
| 2022-03-01 16:00 | 1 | A |
| ... | ... | ... |

**What i want is basically how many ids have event A active at each time in the df, like in the table below.**

| time | eventA |
| --- | --- |
| 2022-03-01 10:00 | 1 |
| 2022-03-01 11:00 | 1 |
| 2022-03-01 12:00 | 2 |
| 2022-03-01 13:00 | 1 |
| 2022-03-01 14:00 | 2 |
| 2022-03-01 15:00 | 2 |
| 2022-03-01 16:00 | 3 |
| ... | ... |

I achieved this with some basic pandas operations:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "time": pd.date_range("2022-03-01 10:00", periods=7, freq="H"),
        "id": [1, 2, 3, 1, 4, 2, 1],
        "event": ["A", "B", "A", "B", "A", "C", "A"],
    }
)
```

```
timestamps = df.time
values = []
for timestamp in timestamps:
    filtered_df = df.loc[df.time <= timestamp]
    eventA = filtered_df.groupby("id").last().groupby("event").count().["time"]["A"]
    values.append({"time": timestamp, "eventA": eventA})

df_count = pd.DataFrame(values)
```

In my case though, i have to go over >50,000 rows and this basic approach becomes very inefficient time wise.

Is there a better approach to achieve the desired result? I guess there might be some pandas groupby aggregation methods that could help here, but i found none that helped me.

Comment: `df.value_counts(['time', 'event']).unstack()`.

Comment: @RaymondKwok That doesn't seem to get the expected result for me. Can u elaborate how this should work? I added a snippet to create the dataframe so you can try it out.

Comment: @RaymondKwok's answer work fine. If you are unfamiliar with these method you can have a look at the first two steps in my answer.

Comment: @fstermann, I think I missed out something. One moment.

Comment: @rpanai Both your answers basically do a one-hot encoding, disregarding the id. What i want to achieve is the result specified in my second table. Basically how many ids have event A as their last event. E.g. at 10:00, only id1 has event A, at 12:00 also id3 (so count should be 2 now), but at 13:00 id1's event is now B, so count drops to 1 again. Sorry if my formulation above was unclear.

Comment: It's my bad. I have added an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df.set_index(['time', 'id']).unstack().fillna(method='ffill')\
    .stack().value_counts(['time', 'event']).unstack().fillna(0)
```

The first line takes care of getting the latest event from each `id` at each hour by forward-filling the `NaN`s

```
                    event               
id                      1    2    3    4
time                                    
2022-03-01 10:00:00     A  NaN  NaN  NaN
2022-03-01 11:00:00     A    B  NaN  NaN
2022-03-01 12:00:00     A    B    A  NaN
2022-03-01 13:00:00     B    B    A  NaN
2022-03-01 14:00:00     B    B    A    A
2022-03-01 15:00:00     B    C    A    A
2022-03-01 16:00:00     A    C    A    A
```

The second line does the counting and thus

```
event                  A    B    C
time                              
2022-03-01 10:00:00  1.0  0.0  0.0
2022-03-01 11:00:00  1.0  1.0  0.0
2022-03-01 12:00:00  2.0  1.0  0.0
2022-03-01 13:00:00  1.0  2.0  0.0
2022-03-01 14:00:00  2.0  2.0  0.0
2022-03-01 15:00:00  2.0  1.0  1.0
2022-03-01 16:00:00  3.0  0.0  1.0
```

Comment: Sorry, I somehow miss clicked and accepted the “wrong” answer  Yours is the correct one!

Comment: No worries. I just felt strange and wanted to make sure that you saw my version. Looking at your problem from a different perspective does save a lot of computation, doesn't it?